# Chessboard distance in the image matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, distance

Given an image matrix, how can I get the locations of the pixels whose chessboard distances from pixel **A** is less than **D**. I need to performed this for all pixels.

Using the MATLAB function `bwdist` I couldn't provide desired result. What's the solution?

```
[D,idx] = bwdist(Img,'chessboard');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an image, pixel and maximum distance:

```
% Test image
Image = zeros(20,30);

% Maximum chessboard distance from image
maxDist = 7;

% The pixel from which to measure distance
pix = [4,19];
```

To find the pixels who's chessboard distance from the `pix` are 
less than `maxDist` and in the image bounds:

**Option 1:** Using `bwdist`

```
% Create a binary image with all pixels zero except 'pix'
bw = zeros(size(Image));
bw(pix(1), pix(2)) = 1;

% Get the chessboard distance transform
[D,idx] = bwdist(bw,'chessboard');

% Get the linear index of 'pix' 
pixInd = sub2ind(size(bw), pix(1), pix(2));

% Find linear indices of pixels who's chessboard distance from pixel are 
% less than 'maxDist'
pointsInd = find(idx == pixInd & D < maxDist);

% Remove 'pix'
pointsInd(pointsInd == pixInd) = [];

% Get the pairs of (x,y) of the pixels
[pointsX, pointsY] = ind2sub(size(bw), pointsInd);
```

**Option 2:** Using `meshgrid`

```
% Get the range of x and y indices who's chessboard distance from pixel are 
% less than 'maxDist' and in the image bounds
xRange = max((pix(1)-(maxDist-1)),1):min((pix(1)+(maxDist-1)),size(Image,1));
yRange = max((pix(2)-(maxDist-1)),1):min((pix(2)+(maxDist-1)),size(Image,2));

% Create a mesgrid to get the pairs of (x,y) of the pixels
[pointsX, pointsY] = meshgrid(xRange, yRange);
pointsX = pointsX(:);
pointsY = pointsY(:);

% Remove 'pix'
pixIndToRemove = (pointsX == pix(1) & pointsY == pix(2));
pointsX(pixIndToRemove) = [];
pointsY(pixIndToRemove) = [];
```

**Displaying result:**

```
% Get linear indices of pixels
pointsInd = sub2ind(size(Image), pointsX, pointsY);

% To display the result, create a binary image with all found pixels 
% colored white
bwPoints = zeros(size(Image));
bwPoints(pointsInd) = 1;

% Show points
imshow(bwPoints, 'InitialMagnification', 2000)

% Show pixel grid lines
hold on
[rows, cols] = size(bwPoints);
for row = 0.5 : 1 : (rows + 0.5)
    line([0.5, cols+0.5], [row, row], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 0.5);
end
for col = 0.5 : 1 : (cols + 0.5)
    line([col, col], [0.5, rows+0.5], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 0.5);
end
```

[image]

**Efficiency and running in a loop over all image pixels:**

**Option 2** is way much faster than **Option 1**. I wrote first **Option 1** because `bwdist` was mentioned in the question. Running **Option 2** in a loop can be improved by calculating the pixels first and than shifting them to the location of each pixel:

```
% Get the range of x and y indices who's chessboard distance from pixel 
% (0,0) are less than 'maxDist'
xRange = (-(maxDist-1)):(maxDist-1);
yRange = (-(maxDist-1)):(maxDist-1);

% Create a mesgrid to get the pairs of (x,y) of the pixels
[pointsX, pointsY] = meshgrid(xRange, yRange);
pointsX = pointsX(:);
pointsY = pointsY(:);

% Remove pixel (0,0)
pixIndToRemove = (pointsX == 0 & pointsY == 0);
pointsX(pixIndToRemove) = [];
pointsY(pixIndToRemove) = [];

for x=1:size(Image, 1)
    for y=1:size(Image, 2)
        % Get a shifted copy of 'pointsX' and 'pointsY' that is centered
        % around (x, y)
        pointsX1 = pointsX + x;
        pointsY1 = pointsY + y;

        % Remove the the pixels that are out of the image bounds        
        inBounds =...
            pointsX1 >= 1 & pointsX1 <= size(Image, 1) &...
            pointsY1 >= 1 & pointsY1 <= size(Image, 2);

        pointsX1 = pointsX1(inBounds);
        pointsY1 = pointsY1(inBounds);

        % Do stuff with 'pointsX1' and 'pointsY1'
        % ...

    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the working solution. It seems OK but there is a trivial issue with that: the location  of the  target pixel (pix) is included in [pointsX, pointsY]  pairs that should not be so.

Comment: @dtr43: I edited the answer and removed the  the target pixel

Comment: It works but in an examplary case (for a 434*700 pixel image) for calculating the chessboard distances for all the pixels the option 1 (your proposed solution) has been leveraged within two for loops. Additionally, there is another internal loop that calculates the euclidean distances between the target pixel and surronding pixels within the chessboard distance. This process is highly time-consuming and inefficient. Is there any trick to make that more efficient?

Comment: @dtr43: Option 2 is much faster. I edited the answer and added a section about: **Efficiency and running in a loop over all image pixels**

Answer (score 3):

> *"The aim is to access the location of the pixels whose chessboard distances from pixel **A** is less than **D**. The process should be
>   performed for all pixels..."*

Since **D** is creating a square selection area, just use simple maths..

For example: if **D** is 3 then from the [x,y] position of pixel A...

```
//# we minus D by 1 since you want less than D (not equal / higher)

Start-X = pixelA.x - (D-1); //from the left
End-X = pixelA.y + (D-1); //to the right

Start-Y = pixelA.y - (D-1); //from the top
End-Y = pixelA.y + (D-1); //to the bottom
```

That will give you a square perimeter that represents your required selection area.

Look at this example image below: 
 Each square is a pixel. If the "crown" icon represents pixel **A** and **D** is 3 (where your *"less than **D**"* means **D** has a maximum length of 2 pixels), can you see how the pseudo-code above applies?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'm afraid if it can compute diagonal neighborhoods.

Comment: If I haven't misunderstood your comment... `(1)` Step one pixel left/right and also step one pixel up/down for diagonal travel. `(2)` Repeat step (1) until all diagonal pixels are covered.